# All recent badges "Yearling"?

Tags: discussion, badges

I just loaded the SO homepage, and every one of the "Recent Badges" listed down the right-hand side was a "Yearling" badge.

Did I just happen to arrive right after some cron job had run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the others said, Yearling is issued daily, and all those users signed up on 25 Sep (2008 and 2009). Here's a list of the creation dates of all the accounts listed as receiving Yearling on the homepage right now: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/11723/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the cron job for Yearling runs at midnight UTC.

Comment: This would have been around 0045. I'm surprised that it went that long without something else being added - but it's the weekend. Meh :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Ed Well, maybe a little after midnight. I don't think anyone has actually sat down and watched the badges that closely.

Answer (score 3):

The job that checks when "Yearling" should be awarded presumably only runs once a day...so yeah, you probably arrived at the "right" time.