# Eeeek! Hot Network Questions killed recent tags and recent badges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hot-questions, homepage, sidebar

I was really used to see the "recent tags" and "recent badges" on the homepage of each site.

Now both are no more, replaced by the hottest 12 questions of the network  - same list on all sites.

Yes I know it was [announced here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198613/152859):

> We're going to try putting the hot network questions on the homepage - replacing recent tags and recent badges.

But while I like the hottest questions list, I would also like to still see or at least have access to the good old recent tags and recent badges list.

There is plenty of vertical space in the homepage of each site, showing 50-100 questions so why not leave those lists below the hot questions?

**Edit**: just noticed the "Recent Badges" moved to the [Badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges), I can live with that... so can a new tab "recent" be added to the [Tags page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) as well?

Comment: I wonder if the new position will be more or less noticable. I must admit I hadn't noticed the hot network questions on the meta homepage until... well now

Comment: I never could figure out what use the recent badges section was. It was almost always at least 50% "Yearling" any time I noticed it.

Comment: Why not just add them as tabs on the 'Tags' and 'Badges' pages respectively? Are you really referring to them regularly enough to merit real estate on the front page?

Comment: @Richard well, that's the first thing I spotted. I waited for a while to see if it will be removed... but looks like it's here to stay.

Comment: @Geobits: for me it was all random users getting Tumbleweed badges and Jon Skeet getting **Yet More Nice/Good/Great Question/Answer Badges™**.

Comment: @Geobits I disagree, it used to show diverse tags - not perfect and I even suggested [to make it more diverse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192456/152859) but still... it wasn't 50% Yearling.

Comment: @jmac wow, I just noticed the [badges page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) now have the "recent badges" list in the sidebar! For the life of me, can't remember if it's new or always was there.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I just [look at the right(wrong) time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65694/212780).

Comment: see also: [Extend the new Hot Questions sidebar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209775/extend-the-new-hot-questions-sidebar)

Comment: @Sha, yeah, like that -- only with tags too. And as tabs rather than just a side bar. I mean, if they have the info anyway, it should be accessible, but no need for it on the front page, right?

Comment: @jmac yes, new tab in the tags page would make sense, edited my request.

Comment: @Geobits no, more like "recently used". :)

Comment: @jmac, on SO, the "recent badges" doesn't show much that's interesting, that's true. However, the real estate is currently *unused*, so there is no associated cost, & there is a benefit on sites that aren't as crowded as SO (ie, almost all of them), where the recent badges can alert people to questions & answers that are trending or high-quality, etc.

Comment: @gung, white space is not 'unused', it has value in being left blank. Shall we extend the page to the margins on both sides? Indent questions and answers around the score voting arrow bit? remove as much spacing between things as possible? After all, all that space is unused too... My point being that just because there is space to put something doesn't mean something should be put there, especially if even the proponents say they "don't show much that's interesting"

Comment: @jmac, the *only* site where I suspect they "don't show much that's interesting" is SO. There are 112 SE sites. There is no doubt that some whitespace is useful. No one is advocating eliminating all whitespace on the main page. But the space that used to house the recent badges is now less useful than before.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I closed mine and upvoted yours :)

Comment: @mehow lost cause, see the dev's answer but thanks anyway. :-)

Answer (score 8):

The badges still live on ...[the badge page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Recent tags are not available anymore, however [the tag page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular) contains similar data, except rolled up by tag.

Comment: You mean the "X asked today, Y this week" for each tag? Well, this does make some sense. So it's a plain "no" for bringing it back to the homepage? :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd we clearly do not have a plan to "bring it back" on the home page or we wouldn't have removed it in the first place. I think that if a reasonable case is made, which I would expect to include a new home for it, then something can be arranged :-)

Comment: My case is just users sharing my opinion, not that strong. Was worth a shot, feel free to remove the discussion tag and add nice red [meta-tag:status-declined] then to put this request into proper rest. :)

Comment: The tag page doesn't really provide *quite* the same functionality... However, [it certainly *could* do so.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99356/feature-request-hot-tags-or-popular-tags-sorted-by-week)

Answer (score 2):

The recent badges and tags list serve no useful purpose in my opinion. They might be somewhat entertaining, though I never use them at all, but they aren't actually useful. I don't think we should clutter up the sidebar with items of questionable value.

If some users actually want to keep those lists, they should be put on a separate page linked from some appropriate place, and not on the frontpage.

Comment: They were there for long years, so guess the team had some reason adding them. I consider them "useful stats", if nothing else. :(

Comment: I never cared about recent tags, but on sites where I'm a mod or "senior user" I use recent badges *all the time* to get a sense of what's going on on the site, particularly involving new users (who I want to encourage).  And if somebody does something significant on a small beta like earn Research Assistant, I want to call that out -- congratulate him in chat, encourage others, etc.  I'm glad to see that this list is on the badges page now (which is totally fine with me; I don't mind clicking for this info).