# Could recent gold (or silver or bronze) badges be shown somewhere separately?

Tags: feature-request, badges

On the pages explaining [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges), list of recent badges is shown on the right. (They have been moved there [from the frontpage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209906/eeeek-hot-network-questions-killed-recent-tags-and-recent-badges).)

One reason I find list of recent badges interesting is that it shows achievements by users of particular sites. This might help me to notice some interesting posts or some remarkable thing a particular user was able to do.

The gold badges seem to be the most interesting from this viewpoint. (Admittedly, there are even gold badges which are easy to obtain, such as fanatic badge. But, in general, it is more difficult to get a golden badge than silver or bronze one.)

I think that an appropriate place for list of gold/silver/bronze badges could be on the badges page, when choosing to display only [gold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=gold), [silver](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=silver), [bronze](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=bronze) badges.

> **Feature request:** Could we have on the badges page in the view for gold/silver/bronze badges the list of recently awarded gold/silver/bronze badges (instead of the list of all recent badges, which is shown there now)?

Comment: @cVplZ I don't see an option to sort *the list of recent badges* by class. Where is it? (Notice that I provided links to list of explanation for badges separately for gold/silver/bronze badges. I am aware of that one. But I am asking about list of recently awarded badges.)

Comment: @cVplZ You wrote: *The recent badges show like 50 badges per page.* If I am not mistaken, I can only see 50 most recent badges. (I don't see there a possibility to click there to get on another page with 50 badges before them.) And between the 50 most recent badges there are usually no gold badges. *I see no overwhelming reason to have this implemented.* I do not claim that it is important to have such a list. I think it would nice to have such a list. In any case, I posted this feature request. Other users can also show their opinion on this by voting and commenting.

Answer (score 5):

Until this feature request is implemented you can use the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/241589/all-gold-badges) to list all recent awarded goldbadges. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to add the silver and bronze badges.

```
with goldtagbadges as 
(select max(badges.id) as Id
 from badges
 inner join tags t on t.tagname = name
 group by userid, name
 having count(*) > 2 )

select Name, [UserId] as [User Link], [date] as [Awarded] 
from badges 
where name in ( 'Socratic'
, 'Stellar Question'
, 'Great Question'
, 'Famous Question'
, 'Illuminator'
, 'Great Answer'
, 'Populist' 
, 'Reversal'
, 'Unsung Hero'
, 'Fanatic'
, 'Legendary'
, 'Marshal'
, 'Constable'
, 'Sheriff'
, 'Steward'
, 'Copy Editor'
, 'Electorate' 
, 'Publicist'
) union
select Name, [UserId] as [User Link], [date] as [Awarded] 
from badges 
inner join goldtagbadges g on g.id = badges.id
order by [date] desc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the query!

Comment: My attempt at *exercise left for reader*: [Most recent silver badges](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/257766/most-recent-silver-badges), [Most recent bronze badges](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/257768/most-recent-bronze-badges) (Admittedly, these are less interesting - gold badges represent bigger achievements.)